# Does supervisor block calls while restarting children?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I'm trying to understand what's happening here:

I have a supervisor that is cyclically restarting one client without triggering the `MaxR, MaxT` mechanism.  The client just crashes slowly enough never to trigger the rate limitation.

There would have been another mechanism that uses `supervisor:which_children/1` and `delete_child/2, start_child/2` to adapt the set of children to reality (its scanning for USB devices trying to have one supervisor child per device found).

This would normally behave like a safety net to the rate limitation, but strangely it looks like the mechanism that deletes and starts children is not called at all.

To find out what's going on I called `supervisor:which_children/1` from the shell and it looks like the call just blocks and never returns.

Can it be that calls to the supervisor are blocked while it is busy trying to restart a child?

**Addendum:**

it looks like the crash happens during child start:

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 29-Mar-2011::21:36:20 ===
     Supervisor: {local,gateway_sup}
     Context:    start_error
     Reason:     {'EXIT',{timeout,{gen_server,call,[<0.155.0>,late_init]}}}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.76.0>},
              {name,gw_3_5},
              {mfa,{channel,start_link,
                            [[{gateways,[{left,108},{right,103}]}],
                             {3,5}]}},
              {restart_type,transient},
              {shutdown,10000},
              {child_type,worker}]
```

Comment: Are you making a `gen_server:call` in the `start_link` function of the child?

Comment: Yes I do.  I need some late initialization that needs to be done after the gen_server is already running.

Comment: Why don't you do this in the `init` function instead? Seems that there may be risk for dead lock here...

Comment: @Adam: the stuff in late_init needs the gen_server already running (needs the pid of the gen_server).  I don't see any deadlock possibility here (and the reason for the timeout is known).  You can see the code here http://ideone.com/KtM6N

Comment: Your problem aside, you should be able to just run `self()` in the `gen_server` process to get it's own pid.

Comment: @Adam: I'm calling self() in the gen_server late_init handler, thats why I need it to be running.  Your second comment refers to my other question which is only loosely connected to this one.  I really want to know if a supervisor can't be called while it is restarting children.

Comment: `late_init` is not needed at all. You can call `self()` inside `init` in the `gen_server`.

Comment: Yes, but if the stuff that is called in late_init needs to call back API functions of my gen_server I really need it to be running.  And when I do call these during init I really get a deadlock.

Comment: But `late_init` is already a call to the `gen_server` you would get a dead lock anyhow. Are you saying you have an advanced set up protocol once the `gen_server` is started? In that case you should not run that inside the `start_link` function. The supervisor should not be involved in such communication at all. Preferably starting a process should be a fire-and-forget operation as far as the supervisor is concerned.

Comment: Sorry but no.  I added the code to the question, you see that first the gen_server:start_link is called and after this succeeded I call late_init.  And I see no deadlock when running it it just works fine.

Comment: The code you posted is not needed as I stated above. Unless you want to add more process communication later (as you said) and in that case my previous comment applies.

Comment: Hmm, just removed the late_init stuff ... and it still works right from init.  Problem is I forgot what I was fixing with this.  Ok I take back everything and you are right :-)  I think I'll remove the code not to confuse anybody and make them repeat my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question besides the discussion is:

When restarting a child that fails during startup the supervisor loops inside its process (it is a gen_server internally) not handling any API calls to it.

So it is especially bad if the rate limitation of the supervisor is configured that it will not trigger on startup errors of the children.  I have a slow startup (especially on error) in my example.

So if the supervisor loops forever trying to restart a child it is not reachable for any calls to it ... which is usually bad.

Comment: The best thing is to strive for a as simple init phase as possible, and do the rest after the processes are started. The benefits of this are twofold, first the supervisor is involved as little as possible (and not being blocked, as you have discovered is the case with many restarts and long init phases) and secondly the process is protected by the supervisor monitoring it from the start (if something goes wrong in the later setup, this is handled by the supervisor).

Comment: Amen to that! I've had some very unpleasant experiences with complex `init` callbacks (starting other processes, reading files etc).