# Supervisor tree exits instead of restarting child process

Tags: elixir

My problem is a lot like the one described here [Supervision tree failing to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407088/supervision-tree-failing-to-start), and the offered solution seems more or less identical to what I have, except mine just exits when a child process fails with this message: `** (Mix) Could not start application server: Server.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Server.Gen.StartRabbit`. I was wondering how I can get it to "restart" (or rather retry starting since it hasn't actually started yet). Thank you!

```
defmodule Server do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      {
        GenRegistry,
        worker_module: Server.Gen.Rabbit
      },
      Server.Gen.StartRabbit,
      Plug.Cowboy.child_spec(
        scheme: :http,
        plug: Server.Router,
        options: [
          port: String.to_integer(System.get_env("PORT") || "3000"),
          dispatch: dispatch(),
          protocol_options: [idle_timeout: :infinity]
        ]
      )
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Server.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

```
defmodule Server.Gen.StartRabbit do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_opts) do
    Enum.each(0..5, fn x ->
      GenRegistry.lookup_or_start(Gen.Rabbit, Integer.to_string(x), [
        %Gen.Rabbit.State{id: str_id, chan: nil}
      ])
    end)

    {:ok, %{}}
  end
end
```

Comment: The code you provided does not even mention `Server.Gen.StartRabbit`. I guess it is started from `GenRegistry`, so, please, provide its code.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks! I just updated the code to include the reference and the code for `Server.Gen.StartRabbit`. I had pasted stale code originally.

Comment: Well, the plot thickens. Now I believe the issue is within `GenRegistry.lookup_or_start/3`. Please share it as well.

Comment: sorry. I'm not sure I fully understand, since I thought `GenRegistry` was a native module: https://hexdocs.pm/gen_registry/readme.html

Comment: What do you mean “native”? It’s a third party library unknown to me. I am not sure what are advantages of using it against core [`Registry`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html) module and I surely have zero ideas about what goes wrong there. It might use `handle_continue/3`, for instance, delaying the process start for too long, or like.

Comment: oh. my mistake! yes, it is a 3rd party library. I found the reason was related to the https://github.com/pma/amqp library, which has its own way of enabling reconnecting per https://github.com/pma/amqp/issues/31 . I was asking in a way that was library-agnostic since I expected the answer to be a broad elixir-wide one, so I can apply this to any external db that may be down like postgresql.  Thanks again!

Comment: AMQP library does not have its own way of reconnecting, it’s a very common OTP approach: one monitors the process, traps exits and respawns the process when necessary. `Registry` does not supervise anything, it allows dispatching messages to the named processes only. I am not sure I understand what are you actually asking.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin. sorry for the confusion. I'm still learning Elixir and Mix and while a rabbitmq consumer genserver is able to reconnect the rabbitmq broker upon process failure. would this be better discussed in its own thread? thanks so much again!